# Firebase Performance Monitoring (Angular)

Tags: firebase, firebase-performance

I'm still new with firebase. Is there any way that we can use firebase performance monitoring to monitor our web app screen by screen automatically from the console? I checked the documentation and it says we need to put some traces in the code to trace (correct me if i'm mistaken).

Answer (score 5):

Performance Monitoring automatically provides a trace for page load when you add `AngularFirePerformanceModule` into your App Module's imports.

```
import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire';
import { AngularFirePerformanceModule, PerformanceMonitoringService } from '@angular/fire/performance';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
    AngularFirePerformanceModule,
    ...
  ],
  providers: [
    PerformanceMonitoringService
  ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Check documentation here: https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/performance/getting-started.md and some tutorial here: https://labs.thisdot.co/blog/intro-to-performance-analytics-with-firebase